# Read page from cache on Back but not when clicking a link to the page

Tags: http, caching, browser, cgi

I have a set of interlinked dynamic web pages.

When the user clicks from one page to another, I don't want any caching to happen - the request must go to the server, which will return an up-to-date page.

But when user clicks Back, I *do* want the cache to be used - some of the pages can take some time to generate, which is fine when you're clicking through to them, but not when you're clicking Back.

Is this possible?

(Please don't suggest re-engineering everything as a single page making AJAX queries!)

<sub>(Note: this question is the opposite of the ever-popular "How do I prevent caching when the user clicks Back?" question.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A common trick for avoiding the browser cache when dealing with dynamic pages is to add a parameter to the link url that is unique (using the time, to the millisecond is common).

When the user hits the 'back' button, they will go back to the last rendered version, and should get it from the cache.